# What is this air handling unit in my new UK flat?

Tags: electrical, hvac

Friends just moved into a new, modern flat (UK) and this unit was on the wall in one room, permanently wired on.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help identifying?  There's an internal mesh and an external vent, and a label on the switch "preheat on/off", (the other label on the front is just the installer's logo, a company called Kenwood, not a manufacturer), but it doesn't seem to be an AC unit (too simple/low power, no controls, no compressor), and simple ventilation holes like airbricks, just aren't powered.  The other rooms don't have this. And what on earth is being "preheated" anyway?

The block of flats seems modern ish, full 300mm walls best I can tell (hence adequate insulation), and double glazed. The layout is ground floor, combined hall/reception  room/galley kitchen (4.5x5.5m approx), and large + small bedrooms + bathroom. Heating is standard conbi  boiler+radiators.

So what is it, and why powered?

Comment: Could be air purifier. Check some filter inside. Should be replaceable.

Comment: Possible it might be an air exchanger.  If a building/house is well sealed, an air exchanger is used to push stale inside air out and bring in fresh air.  Pre heat would used when outside air is too cold.

Comment: Hopefully, an air exchanger will moderate the external air coming in by passing through a heat exchanger with the conditioned air passing out. But yes, I could see a pre-heat if it's very cold outside...

Answer (score 1):

New, modern, always on, leans towards something like heat recovery ventilator, but with only one vent (not two, one for in and one for out) it might be simply a positive pressure intake fan (intake presumed because of the preheat) where air exchange is via leakage from the positively pressurized space (and out any vent fan ducts) and no heat is recovered.

Comment: Agreed. The 'preheat' switch likely turns on a heater bank to heat the incoming air.